# How to create an administrator account only used for UAC and prevent from WinLogon?

Tags: windows-7, windows, login, uac, winlogon.exe

I am trying to create an administrator account to be used only as a UAC credential prompt when launching specific command (such as user account creation). I also want to prevent from login with this account on the WinLogon interface.

Is it possible ?

Thx in advance for your answers

Comment: Have you tried flagging the account "Deny log on Locally" *and* "Deny Logon through Terminal Services" ? This would stop them from using remote desktop or the local keyboard to log on, but I'm not sure if it also blocks you from using the account for UAC.

Comment: What Windows edition (Home Premium, Professional, etc.) are you using?

Comment: Yes, it was my first and last idea, it blocks the UAC too ...

Comment: I am using Windows 7 Professional

Comment: Yes I already tried to hide the account, but I does not prevent you from loging in. I want to forbid the logon at WinLogon but stil want to use the account for UAC

Comment: @DarthAndroid Yes, that also blocks UAC elevation attempts: http://i.stack.imgur.com/P5d8A.png